# Get index of object with unique attribute

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to write bot for kuku kube game using selenium. Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def clickOnValidElement(driver):
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#box span")
    styles = [element.get_attribute("style") for element in elements]
    for element in elements:
        if (styles.count(element.get_attribute("style")) == 1):
            element.click()
            break
    clickOnValidElement(driver)

driver.get("http://106.186.25.143/kuku-kube/en-3/")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.play-btn').click()
clickOnValidElement(driver)
```

But it doesn't look an efficient algorithm to me. I think there is another way, not to iterate all list one by one. I'm newbe in python, so please help me find out how to get index of object with unique attribute.

**UPD**
Here is example of *styles* list:

```
[
    'background-color: rgb(88, 83, 124);', 
    'background-color: rgb(193, 188, 229);', 
    'background-color: rgb(88, 83, 124);', 
    'background-color: rgb(88, 83, 124);'
]
```

The question still same: how to get index of the unique element?

**UPD2**
Ok, I updated my algorithm. It's a little bit better, but ... hmm, still belive that thats can be faster :)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def clickOnValidElement(driver):
    try:
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#box span")
        styles = [element.get_attribute("style") for element in elements]
        unique = list(set(styles))
        for style in unique:
            if (styles.count(style) == 1):
                elements[styles.index(style)].click()
                break
        clickOnValidElement(driver)
    except Exception:
        print("Time is out.")

driver.get("http://106.186.25.143/kuku-kube/en-3/")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.play-btn').click()
clickOnValidElement(driver)
```

Comment: Can you provide html code please ? I can't click "Play" button on the website from your code. You are trying to get style list from several spans? What fo you mean by "unique" attribute?

Comment: @Stanjer, source: <div id="box" class="lv2" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"><span style="background-color: rgb(116, 127, 119);"></span><span style="background-color: rgb(221, 232, 224);"></span><span style="background-color: rgb(116, 127, 119);"></span><span style="background-color: rgb(116, 127, 119);"></span></div>
In elements list I have objects representing all spans. Only one span has unique style.Using get_attribute() method I can get their styles to compare.

Comment: and the goal is to click the second one?

Comment: @Stanjer, the goal is to click on span with unique style attribute. http://i.imgur.com/7Yeigyv.png, In first code sample - yep, on a second.

Answer (score 0):

The naive loop-break version, is perfectly Pythonic -- it's concise, clear, and efficient.

The reason for slow behavior of your script is probably due to `selenium web driver`.

Comment: Thx, for answer. I know that selenium isn't fast, but my algorithm isn't efficient too :) I updated question to clarify situation with my list.